# Java applet: Read ttf file - access denied

Tags: java, fonts, applet, appletviewer

I have the following lines in my Java applet init function:

```
try {
  this.font = Font.createFont(
    Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
    new File("fonts/myfont.ttf")
  ).deriveFont(24f);
  GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);
} catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println(ex);
}
```

When I open the applet with the appletviewer, the font is loaded as expected. But when I open the HTML page with any web browser, I get this error in the Java Console:

> java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied (java.io.FilePermission
>   fonts/myfont.ttf read)

and the default font is loaded.

(How) can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access local files with applets---this is by design!

You can (and should) embed the font file inside your `.jar` file, and use `Class.getResourceAsStream` or the like to access it (`Font.createFont` has an overload that takes an `InputStream`, which is exactly the type that `Class.getResourceAsStream` returns).

Comment: I'd like this but I don't know how to do it... Could you please post a code example?

Comment: @elektronikLexikon: I can't (because I think it's straightforward enough to do by yourself), but start by playing with (and reading about) `Class.getResourceAsStream`, making sure you understand how that function locates resources. Put the font file in the correct place (usually in the same location as your `.class` files), then play with it till it works. Once it works, passing it to `Font.createFont` is easy.